# How to use index in MATLAB to find function constraints

Tags: matlab

I want to return the indices of elements which satisfy some conditions *and* the condition that their index should be between some constants `A` and `B`. There is a naive form of implementing this with:

```
inds=find(conditions)
real_inds=find(A<=inds<=B)
```

but it is inefficient and actually I want to limit my search to elements with index between those constants, not all elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about restricting yourself to the range `A`, `B`?
Suppose you have `my_vector` and you wish to find the elements larger than 0.3 and smaller than 0.5 (the "`conditions`"). Limiting yourself to the range `A`, `B` is simply:

```
masked_ind = find(my_vector(A:B) > 0.3 & my_vector(A:B) < 0.5);
real_ids = masked_ind + A - 1; %// correct the offset induced by `A`.
```

By applying the `conditions` on `my_vector(A:B)` you actually don't care how big is `my_vector` and you are only processing elements in the range `A:B`.

---

BTW, have you considered using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1), as suggested by [Andras Deak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204209/1714410), instead of using `find` and the actual linear indices?

```
%// create a mask to keep indices from A to B only
real_inds_logical = false(size(your_vector));
real_inds_logical(A:B) = (my_vector(A:B)>0.3 & my_vector(A:B)<0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Suppose that you have vector `x`, conditions: `x == 7 or ( x > 3 and x < 5)` and you want the search between A and B.

Now define vector `g` as an auxiliar vector of indices:

```
g = 1:length(x);
```

And then get your indices like this:

```
indices = g( (g >= A) & (g <= B) & (conditions) );
```

That in this case is translated to:

```
indices = g( (g >= A) & (g <= B) & (x == 7 | (x > 3 & x < 5)) );
```

This will return the elements of `g` that satisfice the conditions between the extern parenthesis.

---

**An example code**:

Initial values:

```
x = [0.0975  0.2785  0.5469  0.9575  0.9649  0.1576  0.9706  0.9572  0.4854  0.8003];
A = 4;
B = 9;
```

Conditions: `x >= 0.1` and `x <= 0.7`

Code:

```
g = 1:length(x);
indices = g((g >= A) & (g <= B) & (x <= 0.7) & (x >= 0.1));
```

Result:

```
indices =

 6     9
```